# :not pseudo class not working on Android device

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, android-browser

I have the following code in my CSS:

```
img:not(#some_image)    {
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

This CSS sets `margin-top:10px;` for every image, if it's not `id="some_image"`.

This is working on many browsers. But on Android devices this gets ignored, means there's no `margin-top:10px;` at any image.

Is there a way to make the `:not` pseudo class working on Android devices? Or, do I have to set this style manually for every image that is not `id="some_image"`?

Comment: I don't think this need android tag, its useless and has nothing to do with android , android-browser is  sufficient

Comment: He means you shouldn't use the `android` tag in your question as this is not related to `android` but to `android-browser`. Also it seems you can use `:not` perfectly fine in [android browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_selectors_not). So the problem may lie somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what I was doing wrong, since the `:not` pseudo class does work in Android browser.

I had the following code:

```
img:not(#some_image, #another_image)    {
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

But this is wrong syntax.

The right way to exclude multiple elements is this:

```
img:not(#some_image):not(#another_image)    {
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

Android seems to be more `strict` because it's only working if using the right syntax while many other browsers also work with the wrong syntax.